# Makefile: Compiling from directory to another directory

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use Makefile to compile a bunch of `.cpp` files located in `src/code/*.cpp`, then compile each `*.o` in `build/`, and finally generate executable with those in `build/` as well.

I have read a couple answers that I tried to work with but have encountered issues I do not understand.

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -g -c

SOURCEDIR = /src/code
BUILDDIR = build

EXECUTABLE = DesktopSpecificController
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/code/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/code/*.cpp,build/%.o,$(SOURCES))

all: dir $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

dir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/*o $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)
```

I do get the following error, and I am not sure why:

```
Makefile:19: target `src/code/main.cpp' doesn't match the target pattern
```

I also see that when trying to build the EXECUTABLE, it is not using the .o files, so it seems my rule is wrong here.

Comment: Just updated my Makefile slightly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `patsubst` function is wrong; you can't use shell wildcard characters like `*`.  You want:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

Also you should be using `SOURCEDIR` and `BUILDDIR` everywhere, not just in some places (otherwise you'll get inconsistencies).  And finally, your SOURCEDIR value is wrong: it should not start with `/` I expect:

```
SOURCEDIR = src/code

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget SO should be one of your last resorts, _after_ you've tried to work it out yourself.  Here are a few makefile debugging hints: first, the `-p` option will print the entire make database out, including all the values of all the variables.  Also, in GNU make you can use the `$(info ...)` function to print out information such as variable values.  Printing those values would have given you a good clue as to where the problem was.

Comment: To clarify MadScientist's suggestion, `$(info ...)` can be used as `$(info $(SOURCES))`, for example.  It can be inserted immediately after the definition of the variable of interest.